# Rails - How to create the right kind of object from Single Table Inheritance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-table-inheritance

I've set up a Rails project to use Single Table Inheritance because I have two types of `User`s - `Sender`s and `Receiver`s. `Sender`s have a `public_key` property and `Receiver`s have a `phone_number` property. They share `name`, `email`, and `password` properties through `User`.

My issue is that in the `create` function of the `User` controller, I'm trying to create one type or the other - either a `Sender` or `Receiver` - based on the value of a radio button on my signup form.

Here's the setup:

USER MODEL

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :name,  :presence => true, :length => { maximum: 50 }
  validates :password, presence: true

  self.inheritance_column = :user_type

  # We will need a way to know which types with subclass the User model
  def self.user_types
    %w(Sender Receiver)
  end
end

class Sender < User; end
class Receiver < User; end
```

SENDER MODEL

```
class Sender < User
  validates :public_key,  :presence => true
end
```

RECEIVER MODEL

```
class Receiver < User
  validates :phone_number,  :presence => true, :length => 10
end
```

USER CONTROLLER

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  #  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_user_type

  def index
    @users = user_type_class.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    if(user_type.eql? "receiver")
      @user = Receiver.new(user_params)
    else
      @user = Sender.new(user_params)
  end
  ...
  private

    # allow views to access user_type
    def set_user_type
      @user_type = user_type
    end

    def user_type
      User.user_types.include?(params[:type]) ? params[:type] : "User"
    end

    def user_type_class
      user_type.constantize
    end

    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :confirmation_password, :user_type)
    end
end
```

NEW USER FORM

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
...
  <div class="user-type">
    <%= f.label :user_type, class: 'form-control' %>
    <%= radio_button_tag(:user_type, "sender")  %>
    <%= label_tag(:user_type_sender, "I am a Sender")  %>
    <%= radio_button_tag(:user_type, "receiver")  %>
    <%= label_tag(:user_type_receiver, "I am a Receiver")  %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
 ...
<% end %>
```

In the `create` method of the `User` controller, I'm trying to make the correct type of `User` with this `if` statement:

```
if(user_type.eql? "receiver")
  @user = Receiver.new(user_params)
else
  @user = Sender.new(user_params)
```

based on the value recorded in the `User` form here:

```
<%= radio_button_tag(:user_type, "sender")  %>
<%= label_tag(:user_type_sender, "I am a Sender")  %>
<%= radio_button_tag(:user_type, "receiver")  %>
<%= label_tag(:user_type_receiver, "I am a Receiver")  %>
```

However, I *always* wind up with a `Sender` type object from the `else` statement. I'm thinking this means something is wrong with my `if` statement, `if(user_type.eql? "receiver")`; however, I cannot figure out what.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think you do not need `set_user_type` method because you are not using the `@user_type` variable that its setting. Take out `before_action` from top of the controller as well.

Second, in `user_type` method you need to change `params[:type]` to `params[:user_type]` since that's the name of radio button tags in HTML.

```
def user_type
  User.user_types.include?(params[:user_type]) ? params[:user_type] : "User"
end
```

Third, you also need to capitalize the value attributes of radio button tags to "Sender" and "Receiver", because thats what you have in `User.user_types` array.

```
<%= radio_button_tag(:user_type, "Sender")  %>
<%= radio_button_tag(:user_type, "Receiver")  %>
```

*Disclaimer: Not tested, but it should take care of your issues.*